# Use different table column for sphinx search weight sorting

Tags: mysql, sorting, sphinx

Rather than the default sorting in [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/), I would like to sort/weight results based on a field in another table. My schema looks like this:

```
node {
  id
  weight
}

node_text {
  id
  node_id
  text
}
```

(Note: There is only one node_text for each node)

I want to index `node_text`, but be able to return sphinx results ordered by `node.weight`. I am assuming I need something like this:

```
sql_query = SELECT node_id, text from node_text

sql_joined_field = weight from query; SELECT id, weight FROM node ORDER BY id ASC
```

Is this the correct way to search for matches `ORDER BY node.weight DESC`? I would like to be able to run a query like the following:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM nodetest1 WHERE MATCH('foobar') ORDER BY weight DESC; SHOW META;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sql_joined_field`, makes a *field*, you need `weight` to be stored in an *attribute*. Easiest would be a simple join...

```
sql_query = select node_id, text, weight from node_text inner join node using (node_id=node.id)
sql_uint_attr = weight
```

That should then work for you SphinxQL query :)